# Overload Anonymous Functions

Tags: c#, anonymous-function, overloading

Still wrapping my head around Delegates and I'm curious: Is it possible to overload anonymous functions?

Such that:

```
delegate void Output(string x, int y);
```

Supports:

```
Output show = (x, y) => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.ToString(), y.ToString());
```

And:

```
delegate void Output(string x, string y);
```

Allowing:

```
show( "ABC", "EFG" );
```

And:

```
show( "ABC", 123 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't overload a delegate like that.

This is a type

```
delegate void Output(string x, int y);
```

changing it to this:

```
delegate void Output(string x, string y);
```

would redefine it.

It would be kinda like defining two different classes with the same name (in the same namespace).

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use Generic Delegates.

```
public delegate void Output<T1,T2>(T1 x, T2 y);
```